# predictInterval and the which option

Tags: r, predict, lme4

```
multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag <- glmer(allbuster ~ lageutradeshare100 + lnlaggdpp + lagtradeopenP  +                                        colonial + lagtradesharePT + lnlaggdpt  + duration + lndist + nobust +                                     nobustsq + nobustcb + (1 | partnercode) + (1 | caseid),
                                data=sanctions.data.new.scaled, family=binomial(link="logit"),
                                nAGQ=1,control=glmerControl(optimizer="nlminbwrap",
                                optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

I am working on a model (see the code above), and I have been using the `predictInterval` function to calculate the predicted probability and prediction intervals. I've gotten the function to work, but I am a bit confused about the "which" option:

```
plotdf_intraeu <- predictInterval(multi.sanctions.bust.full.ag, newdata = newData, type = "probability", 
            stat = "mean", n.sims = 10000, level = 0.90, which = "all", seed = 234)
plotdf_intraeu <- cbind(plotdf_intraeu, newData)
```

I've read the documentation and the vignette, but I am a little confused as to the `which="all"` option. I am not sure what the difference is between the four available options: `full`, `fixed`, `random`, or `all`. Is there a logic to which option I should use?

Could anyone provide a bit more of an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predictInterval` is in the `merTools` package (it's worth specifying this when you're asking about functions that are not in the base/recommended packages). (`glmer` is in `lme4`, which is also extra, but is more widely used/better known.)

?predictInterval says:

> By drawing a
> sampling distribution for the random and the fixed effects and
> then estimating the fitted value across that distribution, it is
> possible to generate a prediction interval for fitted values that
> includes all variation in the model except for variation in the
> covariance parameters, theta.

Thus

- "fixed" means to incorporate *only* the uncertainty in the fixed-effect parameters;
- "random" means to incorporate *only* the uncertainty due to the variation of random-effect groups around the population mean
- "full" combines these two sources of uncertainty
- "all" returns a data frame with *all three of these values*, with an additional column `effect` that can be "combined" (="full"), equal to any of the random-effects grouping variables (i.e. separating components due to different grouping variables in a model with more than one), or "fixed"

If `include.resid.var` is `TRUE` then the residual variance is also included in the uncertainty.